# mysql - cannot add foreign key constraint when creating a table

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I'm new to sql.

I get this error when I try to create foreign keys:

```
cannot add foreign key constraint
```

when I'm trying to create the ORDERS table. here is my code:

```
drop database if exists Company;
create database Company;
use Company;
create table WORKERS(w_id varchar(4), w_name varchar(20) not null, telephone varchar(12), e_mail varchar(35) unique);
create table CUSTOMERS(customer_id varchar(4), customer_name varchar(20) not null, telephone varchar(12), e_mail varchar(35) unique, credit bool);
create table WAREHOUSE(m_id int unsigned primary key, describes varchar(20) not null, fl char(1));
create table ITEM(p_id int(4) unsigned primary key, p_name varchar(15) not null, p_price float not null);
create table INVENTORY(in_id int auto_increment primary key, m_id int unsigned not null, p_id int(4) unsigned not null, amount int not null,
foreign key (m_id) references WAREHOUSE(m_id),
foreign key (p_id) references ITEM(p_id)
);
create table ORDERS(o_id int auto_increment primary key, customer_id varchar(4),
p_id int(4) unsigned, w_id varchar(4), amount int unsigned not null, 
date_of_order date not null,
foreign key (p_id) references ITEM(p_id),
foreign key (w_id) references WORKERS(w_id),
foreign key (customer_id) references CUSTOMERS(customer_id)
);
```

I put the ORDERS (where I have the problem) on different lines to make it easier to you to read.

I search here for an answer, but didn't found anything specific that answer my question.

anyone got any idea what the problem is? thank you!

Comment: When you create a foreign key, the referenced column needs to be a primary key (or at least a unique key depending on the SQL that you're using). That's not the case for your Workers table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to create a `FOREIGN KEY` relationship to a field in the `WORKERS` and `CUSTOMERS` tables that aren't set up as a `PRIMARY KEY`.

The `FOREIGN KEY` needs to be pointing to a `PRIMARY KEY`.  Change your create script to the following:

```
create table WORKERS(w_id varchar(4) primary key, w_name varchar(20) not null, telephone varchar(12), e_mail varchar(35) unique);
create table CUSTOMERS(customer_id varchar(4) primary key, customer_name varchar(20) not null, telephone varchar(12), e_mail varchar(35) unique, credit bool);
```

A word of caution, though.  I would recommend not using `VARCHAR (4)` as a `PRIMARY KEY` field.  I would recommend using an `INT AUTO_INCREMENT` instead.

Comment: thanks a lot! and yes, I'm agree with you it is better to be auto_increment - but my school want it to be that way... I'm not really sure why.

Comment: Foreign key doesn't have to point to a primary key, it just needs to be an indexed column.

Answer (score 1):

The column of the referenced table should be declared as `primary key` to assign a foreign key. For your `orders` table, `WORKERS(w_id)` and `CUSTOMERS(customer_id)` are not declared as primary key, hence you get the error.

Modified Statements:

```
drop database if exists Company;
create database Company;
use Company;
create table WORKERS(w_id varchar(4) primary key, w_name varchar(20) not null, telephone varchar(12), e_mail varchar(35) unique);
create table CUSTOMERS(customer_id varchar(4) primary key, customer_name varchar(20) not null, telephone varchar(12), e_mail varchar(35) unique, credit bool);
create table WAREHOUSE(m_id int unsigned primary key, describes varchar(20) not null, fl char(1));
create table ITEM(p_id int(4) unsigned primary key, p_name varchar(15) not null, p_price float not null);
create table INVENTORY(in_id int auto_increment primary key, m_id int unsigned not null, p_id int(4) unsigned not null, amount int not null,
foreign key (m_id) references WAREHOUSE(m_id),
foreign key (p_id) references ITEM(p_id)
);

create table ORDERS(o_id int auto_increment primary key, customer_id varchar(4),
p_id int(4) unsigned, w_id varchar(4), amount int unsigned not null, 
date_of_order date not null,
foreign key (p_id) references ITEM(p_id),
foreign key (w_id) references WORKERS(w_id),
foreign key (customer_id) references CUSTOMERS(customer_id)
);
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8abfa)

Comment: The referenced column just has to have an index, it doesn't have to be a primary key, although usually it is.